# Regex for removing part of a line if it is preceded by some word in Java

Tags: java, regex, ide

There's a properties language bundle file:

```
label.username=Username:
label.tooltip_html=Please enter your username.</center></html>
label.password=Password:
label.tooltip_html=Please enter your password.</center></html>
```

How to match all lines that have both "_html" and "</center></html>" in that order and replace them with the same line except the ending "</center></html>". For example, line:

```
label.tooltip_html=Please enter your username.</center></html>
```

should become:

```
label.tooltip_html=Please enter your username.
```

Note: I would like to do this replacement using an IDE (IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans...)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you clarified that this regex is to be used in the IDE, I tested this in Eclipse and it works:

```
FIND:
(_html.*)</center></html>

REPLACE WITH:
$1
```

Make sure you turn on the *Regular expressions* switch in the Find/Replace dialog. This will match any string that contains `_html.*` (where the `.*` [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) matches [any](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) string not containing newlines), followed by `</center></html>`. It uses `(…)` [*brackets to capture*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) what was matched into group 1, and `$1` in the replacement substitutes in what group 1 captured.

This effectively removes `</center></html>` if that string is preceded by `_html` in that line.

If there can be multiple `</center></html>` in a line, and they are all to be removed if there's a `_html_` to their left, then the regex will be more complicated, but it can be done in one regex with [`\G` *continuing anchor*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) if absolutely need be.

---

#### Variations

Speaking more generally, you can also match things like this:

```
(delete)this part only(please)
```

This now creates 2 capturing groups. You can match strings with this pattern and replace with `$1$2`, and it will effectively delete `this part only`, but only if it's preceded by `delete` and followed by `please`. These subpatterns can be more complicated, of course.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (line.contains("_html=")) {
   line = line.replace("</center></html>", "");
}
```

No regExp needed here ;) (**edit**) as long as all lines of the property file are *well formed*.

Comment: +1; aren't there some glib quotes about using regex to simplify problems inevitably ending in (failure|heatbreak|spilled beer)?

Comment: @amorfis: while that's explicitly true, as a practical concern it *probably* doesn't matter.  Easy enough to fix by checking substring start positions with `indexOf(String s)`, however.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(_html).*</center></html>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input_line); // get a matcher object
String output = input_line;
if (m.matches()) {
  String output = input_line.replace("</center></html>", "");   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "label.tooltip_html=Please enter your password.</center></html>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(_html.*)</center></html>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll("$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(.*)<\/center><\/html>/
```

finds you the

```
label.tooltip_html=Please enter your username.
```

part. then you can just put the string together correctly.